# what will happen when i mount a parent in child folder?

Tags: ubuntu, mount

I have a directory `/dir1`, `/dir1/sdir2`. what will happen if I issue the below command:

```
mount --bind /dir1 /dir1/sdir2
```

I thought it will create a directory loop but the loop ends at level 1.

Can anyone kindly explain to me why the above command does not create a directory loop?

Answer (score 1):

In your bind mount, mounts inside the original directory where not propagated further. To do that, use `--rbind`. From [the `mount` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html):

```
Bind mount operation
   Remount part of the file hierarchy somewhere else.  The call is:

          mount --bind olddir newdir

   [...]

   The bind mount call attaches only (part of) a single filesystem, not
   possible submounts.  The entire file hierarchy including submounts is
   attached a second place by using:

          mount --rbind olddir newdir
```

However, this will propagate the submounts only once, so there's still no loop:

```
% mkdir -p foo/bar
% sudo mount --rbind foo foo/bar
% ls foo
bar
% ls foo/bar
bar
% ls foo/bar/bar
```

I don't think there's a way to propagate mounts recursively and infinitely.

Comment: What will happen to /dir1/sdir2 mount point after level 1, will that become a normal directory ?

Comment: If I think each directory like a pointer then it shoud loop right? Am i missing anything?

Comment: What will it loop to? The directory is still the directory, when you mount something on it, that doesn't change the contents of the directory - it just puts a layer on top. That layer isn't carried over everywhere the directory goes, though.